# I want to deploy using the entries that i have in my database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

So i used postgres in development for my django project and have important entries in there and i want to deploy to my app in heroku

is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You just need to export your local database and import it on the Heroku Postgres database. Heroku has a [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) to do just that.

1. Create a dump from your local database. `PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`
2. Upload `mydb.dump` somewhere Heroku can access it.
3. Import to heroku. `heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL`

[Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import)